# NginX split requests by location

Tags: nginx, flask

This kind of the question is not new, but still can't get why it does not work for me.

I've tried to add the 2nd location into my `nginx.conf` as this:

```
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        }

        location /updater {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/;
        }

        server_name api.example.com;
    }
```

The endpoint on the 8080 server:

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "8080-test"
```

The endpoint on the 8081 server:

```
@app.route('/updater')
def index():
    return "8081-test"
```

Check that it works:

```
curl -X GET "127.0.0.1:8080"
8080-test

curl -X GET "127.0.0.1:8081/updater"
8081-test
```

Request on the `/updater` still does not work

```
curl -X GET "https://api.example.com/"
8080-test

curl -X GET "https://api.example.com/updater"
Error: "GET /updater HTTP/1.1" 404 232 "-" "curl/7.47.0"
```

Did I miss something in the configuration?

Comment: You have a trailing `/` on `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081/;` which means the request is changed to `http://127.0.0.1:8081/` instead of `http://127.0.0.1:8081/updater`. Remove the trailing `/`.

Comment: @RichardSmith thank you very much! That is really the key. Before that it worked on the `http://127.0.0.1:8081/updater/updater` but without the trailing slash it works as it should be.