# How to Adapt angular components path while using a Nginx reverse Proxy?

Tags: angular, nginx

I'm using a reverse Proxy in order to run two applications on the same port by using Nginx.
This is my Nginx conf file.

```
server{
  
        listen 80;
        location / {
         proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:8081";
        }
        location /admin {
         rewrite ^/admin(.*) $1 break;
         proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:8085";
        }
}
```

My Angular app running on port 8085 is not handling the rerouting with /admin right. Meaning if I don't specify any header, it works fine (just like in this example) :

```
server{
  
        listen 80;
        location / {
         proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:8085";
        }
        location /admin {
         rewrite ^/admin(.*) $1 break;
         proxy_pass "http://127.0.0.1:8081";
        }
}
```

But not with /admin header.

So, I changed my Routes object in my app-routing.module.ts from :

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'users', pathMatch :'full'},
  { path: 'users', component: ListUsersComponent },
  { path: 'users/:id', component: UserDetailsComponent },
  {path: 'add', component: AddUserComponent}
];
```

To:

```
  const routes: Routes = [
      {path: 'admin', redirectTo: 'admin/users', pathmatch: 'full'},
      { path: 'users', component: ListUsersComponent },
      { path: 'users/:id', component: UserDetailsComponent },
      {path: 'add', component: AddUserComponent}
    ];
```

(I also tried different path configurations like :

```
   const routes: Routes = [
      {path: 'admin', redirectTo: 'admin/users', pathmatch: 'full'},
      { path: 'admin/users', component: ListUsersComponent },
      { path: 'admin/users/:id', component: UserDetailsComponent },
      {path: 'admin/add', component: AddUserComponent}
    ];
```

and many more)

No matter what I get this error in my console.

```
GET http://XX.XX.XXX.XX/main.XXXXXXXXX.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Why do you need a `rewrite`? Take a look on my working example with the routing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68724761/nginx-split-requests-by-location
Also `/admin` is not a "header". You can check your nginx with the external utility (like curl) that it works correctly.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69610410/7121513) answer.